# Parsing the textbox text to date time

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime-format

I am using asp.net 4.0 and using ajax toolkit calander extender to get values in date filed from the user.

I am trying to parse the value in the datetime filld as follows

```
DateTime.ParseExact("10/10/2013", "MM/dd/yyyy", null)
```

Which is not working. I was going throught my code and came to a strange result

When I put `-` inplace of `\` it started woking.

Can anybody explain why it is like that.

Comment: `/` only which is default

Answer (score 2):

```
/ is a culture sensitive data seperator character in your 
format String :`"MM/dd/yyyy"`
```

And the Final argument `null` means you specified to use Current Culture.
Check you current culture. Is it `en-US` ? OR you can also Use `InvariantCulture`

use this:

```
DateTime dt =DateTime.ParseExact("19/10/2009", "MM/dd/yyyy",
                                  new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

OR Use InvariantCulture

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("19/11/2011", "MM/dd/yyyy", 
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[Read MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28VS.80%29.aspx) for complete details.